# Best way to secure or harden ubuntu 16.04 standalone (not a server)

Tags: security

I am looking for a script or checklist that will for hardening stand along ubuntu 16.04.

I've looked at several links and many
Of them are geared toward servers and many are also outdated.

Where is a good place to start that has current info?

Comment: What are some you looked at?

Comment: Ubuntu Server and regular Ubuntu share the same base model, so what works for one is likely to work for the other.

Comment: "for a script or checklist" does not exist. Hardening a server is manual work only correct for that system you are on. A script can not take into account your wishes of what needs to work. And out of the box Ubuntu IS secure. Use a good admin password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define "stand alone".

If system connects to the internet via an ISP, then what's true for a server is true for the desktop:

- use a strong password,
- install only the software that is needed,
- keep system updated,
- do not run software from sudo/root unless absolutely necessary.

Also, consider installing [clamav](https://www.clamav.net/). From cli: `sudo apt-get install clamav`.

If system is not connected to the internet:

- Check out boot sequence interrupts in the bios, and
- consider disabling "autorun" features for usb/uefi/cd/dvd devices.

Comment: Thanks . I just mean not meant to serve a website or web service. I'm connecting to the internet though